# Why doesn't use the variable value inside the function in python

Tags: python, function

Why doesn't the following function take the inner `h` value that is defined in the function body and gives weird results (arbitrary `h` value)?

```
def diff(f): # def not define
       h = 0.001
       return (lambda x: (f(x+h) - f(x)) / h) 
def sin_by_million (x):
    return math.sin( 10 ** 6 *x)
>>> diff(sin_by_million) (0)
826.8795405320026
```

Instead of `1000000`?

Comment: Because your `h` is much too large to have a correct approximation of the derivative in 0.

Comment: also your code is badly formatted (`define` doesn't exist, extra paren before `lamba`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @ThierryLathuille comment, your step `h` is too big. In real life, you should adapt it based on the function and value at which you want the derivative.

Check out [`jax`](https://github.com/google/jax) instead:

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as np

def sin_by_million(x):
    return np.sin(1e6 * x)
```

Then:

```py
>>> g = jax.grad(sin_by_million)
... g(0.0)
DeviceArray(1000000., dtype=float32)
```

The beauty of `jax` is that it actually compiles your call tree using chain rule, and produces some code (the calls after the first one are much, much faster). It also works on multivariate functions and complex code (with some rules though). And it works wonderfully well & fast on GPUs.